# Netbeans Linked Database to Java ( App takes record and save it into table )

Tags: java

I am trying create an app that takes a username and saves it in the table.

This is the error I'm getting:

> [EL Info]: 2016-01-19
>   00:24:22.979--ServerSession(227610345)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd [EL Info]: connection:
>   2016-01-19
>   00:24:23.104--ServerSession(227610345)--file:/C:/Users/M7edShin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SaveBox/build/classes/_SaveBoxPU
>   login successful [EL Warning]: 2016-01-19
>   00:24:23.154--UnitOfWork(171647063)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column
>   'ID'  cannot accept a NULL value. Error Code: 20000 Call: INSERT INTO
>   PRECORDS (ID, USERNAME) VALUES (?, ?)     bind => [2 parameters bound]
>   Query: InsertObjectQuery(savebox.Precords[ id=null ])
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been
>   incorrectly provided for this find operation.

This is the code I'm using:

```
  Precords p = new Precords();
    p.setUsername(txtUsername.getText());

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SaveBoxPU");
    PrecordsJpaController pjc = new PrecordsJpaController(emf);

    try {
        pjc.create(p);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    showTable a = new showTable();
    a.setVisible(true);
```

[Picture of ID properties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpNlI.png)

As you can see, my id is correct (`PRIMARY KEY AND NOT NULL AND UNIQUE`), so why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Precords object does not have id attribute set. So when you are try to insert into table. It is displaying Column 'ID' cannot accept a NULL value.

Try to set id also like.

p.setID(1);//TO-DO some logic to set unique value

It should run successfully.